# Does mongo db.remove block?

Tags: mongodb

I'm about to remove about 50 million documents from a total of 65 million from a mongodb collection.

I'm not so much concerned about the time it would take to complete, but rather about the impact it would have on the performance of the production database during the process.

Does `remove()` block the collection or the database? Does it have any impact on running other queries (`find`, `update`) against the same collection? [Mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) don't mention any locks/blocks

Answer (score 1):

> For storage engines supporting document level concurrency control,
>   such as WiredTiger, yielding is not necessary when accessing storage
>   as the intent locks, held at the global, database and collection
>   level, do not block other readers and writers.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency